# internal server error 500 only on files transferred over ftp not on locally created files, running ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: php, linux, web, ftp, hosting

I am running into an error with uploaded php files, they always return an http 500 error but when I write an identical file in nano on my linux machine the file works perfectly

so far I have tried changing editiors on my windows machine,
uninstalling and reinstalling filezilla,
I have tried vsftpd and proftpd(current is vsftpd)

Comment: And this you care about apache?

Comment: ???????? im running apache2 if you are asking

Answer (score 0):

Then your file permissions are set wrong.
Try chown your webserveruser the files and chmod 755

Comment: I think my problem has something to do with the fact that I am using root to login over ftp, but no matter what I tried I could never log in as any other user over ftp